# I have question about the Polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, polymorphism, treemap

I define class variable map

```
private Map<Double, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>((o1, o2)->-o1.compareTo(o2));
```

But when I can't call its method in class method

```
private void inOrder(BalancedBinaryTree.TreeNode root, double target, int k){
    ...
    map.pollFirstEntry();
    ...
}
```

But when I Fix it into

```
private TreeMap<Double, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>((o1, o2)->-o1.compareTo(o2));
```

Now I can call the method of TreeMap, why is that? Why the Polymorphism loses in this situation?

Comment: You misunderstand *polymorphism*. It does not enable you to access methods of a specific subtype on a variable of its parent type; but, beside allowing the parent-typed variable to take various concrete subclass objects, it also means that behavior of methods (already declared and maybe implemented in the parent or variable type) can vary at runtime depending on the concrete implementation subclass used to create the object.

Comment: thanks, I think I have understand why I wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a variable of type [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) using the [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) implementation. In this case, you will be able to call just the methods that are define in Map. In the second case, you are defining a TreeMap variable so you can call all the extra methods you mentioned.

If, in the first case you would cast to TreeMap you would be able to call the method as well.

Something like this:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class TreeMapCheck {
        static Map<Integer, Double> map = new TreeMap<>();
        static TreeMap<Integer,Double> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ((TreeMap)map).pollFirstEntry();
    }
}
```

This kind of approach would fail if there is a difference implementation than the one you would expect, so one can protect herself/himself from that checking whether the given instance is a TreeMap, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ((TreeMap)map).pollFirstEntry();

    if (map instanceof TreeMap) {
        ((TreeMap)map).pollFirstEntry();
    }
}
```